# how do I get the entire http request line?

Tags: http, go

I am trying to handle a request that has a strange formatting

https://explorer.ether.cards/#/founder/1

currently testing on localhost as

http://localhost:9009/#/founder/1

Is there any way to extract the `/founder/1` ?

I have tried the default and custom muxes but cannot find any way to extract the values.

Comment: `#` indicates a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment), that portion of the path is usually not sent to the server and only handled by a browser. Are you certain you actually get that character, or is it percent encoded? All the known information will be in the[`Request`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request) and  [`URL`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL) values.

Comment: @JimB Perhaps the user agent is not a browser.

Comment: @jub0bs, of course, but in the dozen times I've seen this question before it is a browser and the user is unaware of what `#` is. If the data was there, the first step in debugging would be to print out the various fields of the request to see what the data it contains.

Comment: @JimB Agreed. I was only nitpicking.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Request.RequestURI](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.RequestURI) field to get the HTTP request URI as read from the network.  Parse the value as needed by your requirements.

`#/founder/1`  Is a  [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment).  Fragments are not part of the  HTTP request URI and are not sent to the server by clients.

To access  `/founder/1` on the server, move the value to the path  or a query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Anything after `#` in the URL is considered as the URL fragment.
The design of request URL is not correct here because `#` is being used here as a *part of request path* making `/founder/1` a URL fragment. URL fragment is only a *browser-side concept* and browsers do not send URL fragment to the server side.

So in short, you cannot capture `/founder/1` on the server side.